# How can I play Mystic Sanctuary and not auto-lose to Boil?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Mystic Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMystic%20Sanctuary%5d) is one of the best cards from Throne of Eldraine in eternal formats, because it can be fetched with fetchlands and guarantee a strong draw step. The cost is that it requires islands, which means everything dies to [Boil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoil%5d). It's especially bad since Boil is instant speed.

Is there a way to play Mystic Sanctuary and not automatically lose to Boil if it resolves? Right now all the options I'm seeing are subpar:

- [Force of Negation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForce%20of%20Negation%5d) could counter Boil (it must be Force of Negation since Boil is instant speed, it can cast in response the blue deck doing whatever at the end of the Boil player's turn), but it is obviously not a good solution since it's an inherent 2-for-1, and it's often not great against the rest of the Boil player's deck either.
- There are a variety of blue-producing lands that are not Islands, e.g. [Glacial Fortress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlacial%20Fortress%5d). But they don't trigger Mystic Sanctuary.
- Mana rocks such as [Talisman of Progress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTalisman%20of%20Progress%5d) could produce blue mana, but they're also not ideal because blue decks typically do not want mana rocks.

I'm looking for cards that can be played either maindeck or sideboard that will help the Mystic Sanctuary deck beat Boil. The format is Modern.

Comment: Maybe I am missing (gatherer is down) but how does Mystic Sanctuary/Boil cause you to lose?

Comment: @JoeW Mystic Sanctuary means most of my lands are Islands, and Boil destroys all Islands. Gatherer is down, but the cards are still Googleable (search for e.g. "Boil mtg").

Comment: I see the cards but outside of not being able to use the ability on Mystic Sanctuary I don't see how that causes you to lose.

Comment: @JoeW all my lands are gone, that's equivalent to losing. Or you can think of Boil as a 4-for-1 or better, it's killing 4+, often more, Islands for one spell. Unlike creature-killing sweepers as well, it's not like I can play around Boil by not playing lands.

Comment: I am not sure that losing all of your lands is a problem limited to just this type of deck but is a problem with all decks.

Comment: @JoeW Boil is especially effective against this type of deck because no other deck runs so many Islands (except I guess those that are incidentally running Dryad of Illysian Grove).

Comment: @Allure Is boil really that much of a problem? If this is the only deck running so many islands, are people specifically teching against this?

Comment: With the prevalence of shock lands in Modern, I would be surprised to learn that other blue tournament decks do not play many Islands (as a fraction of their mana-generating lands). And on the other side, I would also be surprised to learn that a significant number of high tier Modern decks play Boil, even in the sideboard.

Comment: More detail regarding my previous comment. Mystic Sanctuary is only the sixth-most commonly played Island type card in Modern, behind both basic Islands and three of the four Island-type shocklands. But Boil is the 16th most commonly played non-creature non-land card in Modern, so I was wrong about that part.

Comment: @JoeW I guess another point is that against these Mystic Sanctuary decks, Boil is very close to a "destroy all lands you don't control" effect, which is obviously game-winning. There are other "destroy all lands" effects e.g. Armageddon, but they are symmetrical - your opponent can't cast spells anymore, but neither can you.

Comment: @Andrew Boil is currently quite widely played in sideboards, the Mystic Sanctuary decks are probably a big part of the reason why. There usually isn't four copies, though. See e.g. https://www.mtgtop8.com/event?e=28334&d=424240&f=MO. According to the same website 12.9% of top decks have an average of 2.0 copies of Boil in the sideboard. Boil can be brought in against most blue decks as well, not just the Sanctuary ones.

Comment: @Allure those numbers sound high in some ways but don't in a lot of others - Modern's entire history has been teching against specific deck types in sideboard, and 13% still means that almost 9 out of 10 of top tier decks don't run boil. The usual response to that tech becoming prevalent is people have to tech against that (no perfect answers here) or honestly, they play something else that's more robust.

Answer (score 2):

The main threat of Boil is that it is a single card that can destroy multiple Islands at once. If you are in a situation where you have multiple Islands to get destroyed, you should be able to have some of them untapped. So you can just handle it like any other threat and play regular countermagic like [Negate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNegate%5d) or [Mana Leak](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMana%20Leak%5d) or [Cryptic Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCryptic%20Command%5d), and keep mana available when your opponent is threatening Boil.

Comment: The problem with this is that Boil is instant speed ... since the blue deck will eventually have to do something (e.g. play a card draw spell on the end of opponent's turn), its mana is tapped, and then opponent responds with Boil. If Boil were sorcery speed, "counter it" would be much easier to do.

Comment: The same thing applies to the other player. If they're always keeping mana up to play Boil in response to you going "shields down", they can't play anything else either. And if they spend their mana, then you can spend yours. This is true of basically any instant-speed spell threat.

Comment: Right, but eventually the blue deck will have to do something, because it can't counter everything. A threat is going to slip through, the blue deck will have to answer it (if both players do nothing the other deck will just win with that threat) and that's when Boil is played.

Comment: If your opponent has a must-counter threat and another 4 mana open and you can only cast one counterspell, you're already in trouble. More generally, if your opponent is playing threats, that means that they're not leaving mana open, which means that you can cast your own spells without fear of Boil. Part of this, I think, is just about having a general understanding of threat evaluation, which admittedly I'm not really qualified to explain.

Comment: No, what happens is they e.g. play a Tarmogoyf on turn 2 before most counterspells are available, or they play two Death Shadows in the same turn of which only one can be countered. These are threats that must be answered. Then they stop playing things into open mana because they don't need to, the blue deck must eventually kill the Goyf or Death Shadow, and that's when they cast Boil. If Boil were sorcery speed then it's much less of a problem - the blue deck can take the hit and use instant-speed answers on end step if the Boil player doesn't cast it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osRMoaKIPes the game at about 1 hour 35 minutes in is a typical example of what happens with Boil. The player dies with three counters in hand because they simply can't afford to hold up counters.

Comment: My primary conclusion from that video is that two-time Pro Tour champion Gabriel Nassif built their deck in a way that appears to be similar to what I suggested. And that opposing player played Boil at sorcery speed, so the fact that it's an instant wasn't even a relevant issue. The lesson there is that sometimes the blue player has to go "shields down" to play their own things, and sometimes they get punished for it, and that's just the way the game goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116952/discussion-between-murgatroid99-and-allure).

Answer (score 2):

[Terra Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerra%20Eternal%5d) from Worldwide makes all your lands indestructible.  It's 3 mana, so it comes down the turn before Boil is possible, but it does necessitate a white mama source.

Answer (score 1):

[Pact of Negation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPact%20of%20Negation%5d) is another counterspell you can play while tapped out. For a counterspell, it does cost quite a lot at five mana, but at least it's not a 2-for-1.

Answer (score 1):

Countering the boil is going to be your best bet. If you're playing islands you have most of the counters in the game already in your color and having mana open isn't uncommon for blue decks. Force of Negation isn't the only counter, or the only option with no open mana since [Pact of Negation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPact%20of%20Negation%5d) works for 0 mana up front also.

[Splendid Reclamation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSplendid%20Reclamation%5d), [The Mending of Dominaria](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Mending%20of%20Dominaria%5d) or [World Shaper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorld%20Shaper%5d) could be used for a come back post boil, since all three are a method of "reanimating" your destroyed lands.

[Titania, Protector of Argoth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTitania%2c%20Protector%20of%20Argoth%5d) can make mass land destruction a benefit for you rather than a problem, giving you a field of big creatures in exchange.

Cards like [Cranial Extraction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCranial%20Extraction%5d), [Lost Legacy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLost%20Legacy%5d), and [Memoricide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMemoricide%5d) can simply remove all copies of boil from the game. [Extirpate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExtirpate%5d) and [Surgical Extraction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSurgical%20Extraction%5d) require targeting a copy already in the graveyard, so they are not as good, though the phyrexian cost of Surgical makes it less an imposition on a mana base. [Sadistic Sacrament](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSadistic%20Sacrament%5d) works if they only have 2 or 3 copies sideboarded in, though the [image: {B}][image: {B}][image: {B}] cost is going to be very hard to splash.

None of these are amazing answers, most require a second color, but there should be no "perfect" answers in magic, when there is we tend to see the cards involved get banned for being broken.